# Calling external API once and cache it

Tags: php

I am using a 3rd party API for flight data using a curl call.
After I made the curl call, I parse the data and insert it into a db for caching.(API Calls are not free)

Whenever multiple users make the same request for a flight the same time, it calls the external API multiple times, because it takes some time to make the curl call parse the data and then insert into the db.
So all requests check the db, realise it's not in there, and start calling the external API. When finished, it realises it already has the flight data and stops making a db insert call.

How do I prevent this using best practices?

```
    $flightnum = $_POST['flightnum'];
    if (isFlightInDB($flightnum))
        return json_encode (getFlightFromDb ($flightnum));
    else {
        $flight = callFlightApiAndCache($flightnum);
        return json_encode($flight);
    }
```

Comment: you can search user request first in `DB` if it found then show the result otherwise call your api

Comment: You are not reading my question, it is about multiple requests and timing

Comment: Please show your current code (or a simplified version of it) - i can think of a few ways to handle this but there is no point guessing. Also, does this actually happen very often?? If not you could end up adding complexity to your codebase for little, if any, gain

Comment: why not have a background job that checks the data in table and make the api call, instead of same process triggered by user?

Comment: It is a blocking process, I can't return nothing in my API call

Comment: I added some code that should explain what I'm trying to do, no real code though. Imagine multiple request coming in and running this code, 3 or 4 all end up calling the api

Answer (score 2):

The simple workflow here is to remember that the request on the API is already been made. If you where using Node.js, it would be very simple, because Node.js is a single application, and all requests would be ran on that single instance, so you could have an array where you could store all API requests being currently executed, and implement some logic to wait for the results, read from the database, or execute teh API call.

The main issue is that queries will be executed by PHP in separate server threads, and storing the queries in a database or a local file would be too slow to guarantee you would not execute the API call multiple times.

However, there is an API in PHP which allow you to share an array across PHP execution threads. Take a look to shm_put_var() / shm_get_var(). The idea would be this:

- you get a query from a client
- you get the shared array using shm_get_var()
- you store the API query right away if not already present to block further calls.

  - If already present: either wait for the DB entry to appear or return the DB entry, remove the shared array record -> then exit.
- check the DB if it has an entry: return the DB entry, remove the shared array record -> then exit.
- execute the API call, and store the result in the DB
- remove the shared array record
- exit